# SQLite Android inserção de dados

Tags: android, sqlite

Qual é a melhor forma de inserir mais de 10000 linhas de dados numa tabela constituída por 13 colunas usando o SQLite Android?

Eu pensei em usar o `ContentValue` depois em seguida:

```
Db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, ContentValue);
```

Comment: Qual é a forma que você está pensando usar?

Comment: Eu pensei em usar o ContentValue depois em seguida  Db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, ContentValue);

Comment: @Ludger, pelo que eu li, a cada `insert` que você faz o SQLite cria uma transação, o que torna lento se você sabe que nenhuma `constraint` vai falhar. Muita gente recomenda usar apenas uma `SQLiteStatement` (apenas variando os parâmetros) para velocidade. Dê uma olhada nesse artigo que faz um benchmark: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/turbocharge-your-sqlite-inserts-on-android/ com essas duas alternativas. Assim que eu tiver um tempo eu posso formular uma resposta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não conheço muito do Android em si, mas considerando operações de banco de dados, o ideal seria criar a SQL de insert com parâmetros como

```
INSERT INTO Tabela (A, B, C) VALUES (:A, :B, :C);
```

Dar um `Prepare`, Iniciar uma transação e inserir todos os dados alterando apenas os parâmetros e finalizar a transação.

como foi feito no exemplo citado pelo Wakin neste [artigo](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/turbocharge-your-sqlite-inserts-on-android/), com alguns ajustes:

Segundo o mesmo artigo, através de SQLStatement a velocidade chega a ser 8x superior, nos testes simples que ele realizou

```
private void bulkInsertRecords(String[] records) {
          String sql = "INSERT INTO "+ SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +" VALUES (?,?,?);";
          SQLiteStatement statement = sampleDB.compileStatement(sql); //Este é o prepare
          sampleDB.beginTransaction();
          for (int i = 0; i<records.length; i++) {
                    statement.clearBindings();
                    statement.bindString(1, records[0]);
                    statement.bindString(2, records[1]);
                    statement.bindString(3, records[2]);
                    statement.execute();
           }
           sampleDB.setTransactionSuccessful(); 
           sampleDB.endTransaction();
}
```

### Conclusão

Segundo este [outro artigo](http://tech.vg.no/2011/04/04/speeding-up-sqlite-insert-operations/) o motivo do ganho de performance é:

1. **Controle transacional em bloco**: Com o controle transacional sobre todo o bloco de INSERT, as alterações são realizadas em memória e depois persistida, ao invés de realizar um ajuste na base a cada insert e checkar constraints e atualizar índices, etc.
2. **compileStatement**: É o prepare, evita um overhead de processamento como se cada comando de insert devesse ser verificado, deixando o comando com sua "rota" já traçada, devendo apenas informar os valores

Comment: Há algum motivo, em termos de eficiência, para usar o `SQLiteStatement`?

Comment: @JorgeB. adicionei uma conclusão ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. para termos práticos, o link que coloquei na pergunta tem uma comparação, o ganho é de 17 vezes.

Comment: Sim @Wakim mas o link pode desaparecer. Eu tento não ir ver os links (a não ser que seja documentação) para manter o site fidedigno.

Comment: Usando o SQLiteStatement a app melhorou na perfomance, demora menos tempo a inserir.